# Sending Strings between activities

Tags: java, android

I want to send a value to an activity that `HighScore` which shows the highest score of the game.

I am saving the score at the game activity in shared preferences, and I am trying to send the score(string value) to the activity `HighScore`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, HighScoreActivity.class); 
i.putExtra("classicHighScore", highScore);
```

Comment: You haven't provided the problem you want to solve. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Why do you need to send it to the other activity when you are saving it in the shared preference? You can get the value in any activity without passing it to the activity using shared preference.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are sending your string in an intent.
which means, in your HighScore activity, write

```
String highScore = getIntent.getStringExtra("classicHighScore", "");
```

and there you go, 
String highScore now has your value,

you can log it to check :

```
Log.d("HIGH SCORE VALUE ", highScore);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save data in a SharedPreferences object in the first Activity and read it in the other activity.

Saving the score using SharedPreferences in the first Activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("classicHighScore", highScore);
editor.commit();
```

Reading the score from SharedPreference in the other activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
int score = preferences.getInt("classicHighScore", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want send a String between activities you must create a Bundle.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, HighScoreActivity.class); 

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("classicHighScore", highScore);
i.putExtra(bundle);
```

To read de parameter in HighScoreActivity

```
Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
String classicHighScore = arguments.getString("classicHighScore");
```